# Splice multiple arrays iteratively

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

What is the fastest way to iteratively splice multiple arrays as you go along - without too much performance hit? I imagine it being something like the syntax below but it doesn't quite work.

I'd like to do: Array1 - `remove[0]`, Array2 - `remove[1]`, Array3 - `remove[2]`... and so on...

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = items.name;
    for(key in arr[i]) {
        var value = arr[i].splice(i, 1);
        console.log(value);
    }
}
```

[image]

EDIT (definition of items):

[image]

Desired Result (3 arrays with 1st, 2nd, 3rd items removed, respectively:

```
[array0]
  [0] United Kingdom
  [1] United States

[array1]
  [0] Canada 
  [1] United States

[array2]
  [0] Canada
  [1] United Kingdom
```

EDIT2 - if you look at the following comparison, you can see if we use a for loop to push the incoming arrays into group, the result is identical to the solution provided by Corey, but if we run the splice methods on both of those - the results are very different, example 2 is getting spliced correctly - example 1 is getting spliced entirely, that is where I am confused :

(items are coming in the form of:)

```
["Canada", "United Kingdom", "United States"] 
["Canada", "United Kingdom", "United States"] 
["Canada", "United Kingdom", "United States"] 


var group = [];

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    group.push(items.name);
}

/*for (var i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
   group[i].splice(i, 1);
}*/

console.log(group);

var arr1 = ["One", "Two", "Three"];
var arr2 = ["One", "Two", "Three"];
var arr3 = ["One", "Two", "Three"];

var test = [arr1, arr2, arr3];

/*for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
   test[i].splice(i, 1);
}*/

console.log(test);
```

Comment: Please include the definition of `items`.

Comment: You shouldn't use a `for in` loop on *indexed* arrays. The `for in` loop should only be used for iterating objects of key-value pairs that are not indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of your Arrays are in another "grouped" Array you could just iterate through the group and use the index as your splice counter. Something like:

```
var arr1 = ["One", "Two", "Three"];
var arr2 = ["One", "Two", "Three"];
var arr3 = ["One", "Two", "Three"];

var group = [arr1, arr2, arr3];

for (var i = 0; i<group.length; i++) {
   group[i].splice(i,1);
}

console.log(group);
// Logs: ["Two", "Three"], ["One", "Three"], ["One", "Two"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a third party library, the easiest way is to use Underscore.js.  I'm not clear on whether you want to selectively splice, or if you're just trying to create one array that's a union of the others, or with unique values, or what.  But they have operations for all those things:

http://underscorejs.org/#union

If you dont' want to bring them in, then just look at hte source and see how they do it.

Comment: I am actually using underscore for this project! once I figure out the basic logic I can port it over to the proper method

Comment: Ig uess I don't understand what you're trying to do then; perhaps if you add some more context to your question